# astparser how to set a .java file as an ICompilationUnit in setSource function?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

Instead of having a string as a parameter like this for example:

//parser.setSource("public class A { int i = 9;  \n int j; \n ArrayList al = new ArrayList();j=1000; }".toCharArray());

Answer (score 1):

You can you use  `IJavaProject` [findElement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v6r0m1/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject.html#findElement%28org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath%29) to get the ICompilationUnit.  Or does the file exist outside the project somewhere?

Comment: The file exists outside the project somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need to parse some .java file you can do it by reading it as a char array and setting the parser source via setSource(char[] source). From version 3.6. you can get the bindings as well by using setEnvironment method. More info here [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#Can_I_use_JDT_outside_Eclipse_to_manipulate_Java_code.3F). Not sure does it help much.